# Expo and Next.Js interfering when npm install

Tags: npm, next.js, expo

Im trying to setup a next js with native base and following the instructions, I am getting this.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: next-latest@undefined
npm ERR! Found: next@12.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"12.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer next@"^11" from @expo/next-adapter@3.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@expo/next-adapter
npm ERR!   dev @expo/next-adapter@"^3.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Zacha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zacha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-20T00_16_08_660Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install has failed.
```

Comment: Either downgrade Next.js to v11 to satisfy `@expo/next-adapter`'s peer dependency on `next`, or run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` as the error suggests.

Comment: hey, how did you resolve your issue? @MrZCookie

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Steps.

1. Downgrade your next to 11

   npm install next@11
2. Changes next.config.js to following code.

> ```
> const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');
> const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
> const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
>   'native-base',
>   'react-native-svg',
>   'react-native-safe-area-context',
>   '@react-aria/visually-hidden',
>   '@react-native-aria/button',
>   '@react-native-aria/checkbox',
>   '@react-native-aria/combobox',
>   '@react-native-aria/focus',
>   '@react-native-aria/interactions',
>   '@react-native-aria/listbox',
>   '@react-native-aria/overlays',
>   '@react-native-aria/radio',
>   '@react-native-aria/slider',
>   '@react-native-aria/tabs',
>   '@react-native-aria/utils',
>   '@react-stately/combobox',
>   '@react-stately/radio',
> ]);
>
> module.exports = withPlugins(
>   [withTM, [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }], { webpack5: true }],
>   {
>     webpack: config => {
>       config.resolve.alias = {
>         ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
>         // Transform all direct `react-native` imports to `react-native-web`
>         'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
>       };
>       config.resolve.extensions = [
>         '.web.js',
>         '.web.ts',
>         '.web.tsx',
>         ...config.resolve.extensions,
>       ];
>       return config;
>     },
>   }
> );
> ```

3. Add `import React from 'react';` to _app.js.